# Function to get hours and minutes from two timestamps

Tags: postgresql, function

I would like to create a function to get hours and minutes from two dates. So when start and end dates are passed into the function is returns the difference e.g. HH:MM.

Would be grateful if someone could help or point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asking for hours and minutes it implies your data columns are timestamps (with or without time zone). So you can subtract one from the other which yields an interval. You then use the to_char function to get hours and minutes.

```
select date1, date2, to_char(date2-date1, 'hh24:mi') hr_min
  from source;
```

See [Working with Dates and Times](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL). Also see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a084e8036164b3faf65dc9b12c16915b) for step by step development and also a **caution**.

---

As a function:

```
create or replace 
function elapsed_hr_min(from_ts timestamp
                       , to_ts  timestamp
                       )
 returns text 
 language sql
as $$
   select to_char(to_ts - from_ts , 'hh24:mi');
$$; 

-- test
with source (date1, date2) as
   ( values ( '2010-06-01 12:25:15'::timestamp, '2010-06-01 14:30:15'::timestamp)
          , ( '2020-06-02 23:30:00'::timestamp, '2020-06-03 04:45:15'::timestamp)
   )  
  select elapsed_hr_min(from_ts => date1
                       ,to_ts   => date2
                       )
    from source;
```

Comment: Thanks, Belayer. If I wanted to add minus 5 hours from this can it be done? e.g. output is 06:10 and with minus 5 it would be 01:10.